# Linq-to-sql Compiled Query returns object NOT belonging to submitted DataContext?

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, compiled-query, linq.compiledquery

Compiled query:

```
   public static class Machines
   {
      public static readonly Func<OperationalDataContext, short, Machine>
          QueryMachineById = 
           CompiledQuery.Compile((OperationalDataContext db, short machineID) =>
           db.Machines.Where(m => m.MachineID == machineID).SingleOrDefault()
     );

     public static Machine GetMachineById(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, short id)
     {
        Machine machine;

        // Old code (working)
        //var machineRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Machine>();
        //machine = machineRepository.Find(m => m.MachineID == id).SingleOrDefault();

        // New code (making problems)
        machine = QueryMachineById(unitOfWork.DataContext, id);

        return machine;
     }
```

It looks like compiled query is returning result from another data context

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void GetMachinesTest()
  {
     using (var unitOfWork = IoC.Get<IUnitOfWork>())
     {
        // Compile Query
        var machine = Machines.GetMachineById(unitOfWork, 3);
        // In this unit of work everything works… 
        // Machine from repository (table) is equal to Machine from compile query.
     }

     using (var unitOfWork = IoC.Get<IUnitOfWork>())
     {
        var machineRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Machine>();

        // Get From Repository
        var machineFromRepository = machineRepository.Find(m => m.MachineID == 2).SingleOrDefault();
        // Get From COmpiled Query
        var machine = Machines.GetMachineById(unitOfWork, 2);

        VerifyMachine(machineFromRepository, 2, "Machine 2", "222222", ...);
        VerifyMachine(machine, 2, "Machine 2", "222222", ...);

        Assert.AreSame(machineFromRepository, machine);       // FAIL
     }
  }
```

If I run other (complex) unit tests I'm getting as expected:
 ***An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.***

Another Important information is that this test is under TransactionScope (But problem is appearing even without transaction around.)!

I’m using POCOs mapped with DB using XML.

***UPDATE:***
It looks like next link is describing similar problem (is this bug solved ?):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/9bcffc2d-794e-4c4a-9e3e-cdc89dad0e38

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the ObjectTrackingEnabled of the context to false. This helped me in this same situation but I later turn it on while updating and inserting records.

```
DBDataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false; // Read Only
```

Comment: Thanks, I was playing with this before and I was always getting “Data context options cannot be modified after results have been returned from a query..”
Anyway this query is used in multiple places in relation with other queries (for selecting or updating) and therefore I would be afraid to set tracking off.

Comment: To @Michael D.Irizarry: How do you turn the tracking on/off on the same dataContext? I'm getting "Data context options cannot be modified after results have been returned from a query." if try to set tracking to false after CUD operation.